# A problem with integration by parts

Tags: integration

$$\int x^2e^{x^3} \, dx  =\frac{x^3}{3}e^{x^3} - \int x^5e^{x^3} \, dx $$

How to solve this exercise? Integration by parts only makes a larger mess...

Comment: What makes you think you need to use integration by parts?

Comment: The integration by parts was not necessary. But it was useful. Now you know how to find $\int x^5e^{x^3}\,dx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral can be evaluated by using the substitution $t=x^3$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Make the substitution $x^3 = t$